# Only else statement renders in react JS

Tags: reactjs, maps

I'm trying to map through an objects value, then conditionally render them. However, only the else statements renders; the true part of the if never gets to render. I don't know if it's an oversight on my part, but here's what my code looks like:

```
          if (dataResponse.length < 1 ) {
            return <h1 key={key}>No data found</h1> 
          }
          else{
              return <ul className="mt-50 slide-up-fade-in styled" id="stockData" data-testid="stock-data" key={key}>
                    <li className="py-10" >Open: {value.open} </li>
                    <li className="py-10">Close: {value.close} </li>
                    <li className="py-10">High: {value.high} </li>
                    <li className="py-10">Low: {value.low} </li>       
                  </ul>
          }
                
      
              
      }
```

Comment: And you are sure that `dataResponse.length` is <1?

Comment: Yes. I alternate the values producing dataResponse, and render its length on console.

Comment: Put your dataResponse result.

Comment: It returns 0 or 1 depending on the input

Answer (score 0):

Restructuring the statement saved the day

```
{
              dataResponse.length < 1 ? 
              <h4>No data found</h4>
           :
              Object.entries(dataResponse).map(([key, value])=> {
              return <ul className="mt-50 slide-up-fade-in styled" id="stockData" data-testid="stock-data" key={key}>
                    <li className="py-10" >Open: {value.open} </li>
                    <li className="py-10">Close: {value.close} </li>
                    <li className="py-10">High: {value.high} </li>
                    <li className="py-10">Low: {value.low} </li>  
                </ul>
           })
           
           }
```